# Feature filter for shapefile doesn't work

Tags: shapefile, qgis-3

I have a multiline shapefile with EPSG 25832 and want to use the feature filter in the layer properties source tab.
The query looks like this:`"Abweichung" = 'Revier 1 zu Pflegebezirk 1' and "Abweichung" = 'Revier 1 zu Pflegebezirk 4'`
I hope that only these two lines appear in the map. When I test this expression there is no result for the where clause.

Answer (score 6):

Replace your `AND` with an `OR`, then it will work. Currently you're looking for features where the column `Abweichung` contains both expressions - which logically is impossible.

```
("Abweichung" = 'Revier 1 zu Pflegebezirk 1') OR ("Abweichung" = 'Revier 1 zu Pflegebezirk 4')
```

With `OR` you filter for both entries.